# How to correctly create a cron job for a website?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, website, cron

**How do I create a safe and secure cron job for running PHP scripts of my website?**

I'm creating a PHP installation script for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Server. The script copies files from my installation package to `/var/www/mysite` and sets appropriate read/write permissions for default Apache web user account, which is `www-data`:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX /var/www/mysite
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX /var/www/mysite/storage /var/www/mysite/bootstrap/cache
setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX /var/www/mysite/storage /var/www/mysite/bootstrap/cache
```

Now, as the final step of my installation script I have to install cron jobs that call PHP commands on my site, for example, like this one:

```
php /var/www/mysite/artisan notifications:send
```

I have done some research and found multiple options and possible complications, so I'm not sure what would be the most correct and error free way to create a cron job in my situation.

Specific thoughts and questions:

- it seems, the best place to install cron jobs that do not belong to a specific user but to services running in background would be `/etc/cron.d`, right? It also seems safe choice for automated installation process because I won't have to change any existing cron config file from my installation script but just add a new file, if it doesn't exist yet.
- I don't want to run my jobs as root; that might be not good idea for websites, right? So I will need a dedicated user. At first I thought - hey, I already have `www-data` user created for Apache server and with all required permissions for my site, so I could use that, right? But I've read that `www-data` user actually has no permissions to execute shell commands! So, I would have to change the permissions of `www-data` (which seems not a good idea) or I should create a new user account specifically for my cron jobs, such as `mysite-jobs`. But how do I safely check existence of this user and if it does not exist then create the user from my installation script? And how do I specify its permissions so cron can run `php /some/command` as this user but the user itself does not have `/home` nor password and cannot normally login?
- also, I've read that environment variables are not automatically available for jobs in `cron.d`, so I have to specify them in my cron file. Technically, it might look like this, right?

  `SHELL=/bin/sh
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

My guess is that this might also automatically fix the problem of launching PHP commands in the previous point, but I'm not sure if I'm not giving too much permissions here - I don't want the user to execute any shell command or any command from those bin and sbin directories but `php /some/command` only. And also this makes me wonder - if I have to specify SHELL and PATH variables for cron to use for this job only, then maybe it's safe to use `www-data` after all - those environment variables won't leak out of the cron job, right? But I'm not sure if they will be effective for `www-data` at all, considering that it is a "special" account.

- after I create a cron job in `/etc/cron.d`, will it be picked up by cron immediately or do I have to somehow notify cron about new (or possibly updated when I update websites) file?

So, considering all of the above, how should the final cron job look and how do I specify user account with minimal permissions to run my php commands?

Comment: do you need to run this as a oneoff or every so often?

Comment: The installation script will be run many times to deliver updates, which means that new cron jobs might be added in new versions of my website.

Answer (score 3):

No need to over-think it. Since you are using Ubuntu, the crontab takes the id under which to run the cron job (`www-data`). On my server (that runs a MyBB forum) I added this to `/etc/crontab`:

```
# Run DB backups every morning at 06:00 UTC.
0  6 * * *   www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/theforum/task.php 4
```

No need to worry about `PATH` contents if you give a full path to the PHP executable.

Comment: I've read that it's not good idea to modify `/etc/crontab` directly because it might be unsafe to update & merge using automatic tools; see the comment by kasperd under this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/801261/87638 therefore I chose `cron.d`  option, where I could put a file which I'm sure will have entries created only by my installation script.  But thanks for the direct `/usr/bin/php` part - I guess, with direct php execution `www-data` will not need any PATH or SHELL settings, right?